# Storing user state in session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Excuse the extremely newbie question...

Once I have verified the users login credentials, Where should I store the state for whether a user is logged in or not?

Comment: have you rolled your own registration and authentication system?

Comment: The website is just a frontend for a larger system which will be doing the authentication.

Comment: how much information you plan to keep per user

Comment: about 20-30 parameters per session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have validated that your user is OK according to the backend, you can make ASP.NET set an authentication cookie for the user in the response by doing a `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, persistent)`.

From then on, ASP.NET will decrypt that cookie in requests and extract the username from it, giving you access to it via `HttpContext.Current.User`.

To me, it sound like this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You don't normally need to store this state yourself.  If you are using one of ASP.NET's built in authentication mechanisms (e.g. Form Auth) you can simply check: `Request.IsAuthenticated`

Comment: I have a separate backend system which will be doing the authentication

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'separate backend system'?